# Rails :before_save, either create or update record and return false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a form that has 1 field, an email address.

1. When submitted the model calls :before_save
2. Checks to see if the email address exists.

   1. If it does, it creates a new record.
   2. If it does not, it updates a record in another model AND NO record should be created.

Using return false to cancel the before_save for 2.2 but it rolls back the update and cancels the creation where I just want the record not to be created.

Am I on the right path? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you got user A's object, but update user B's row......

Maybe you could find the correct user object in the controller first:

```
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email]) || User.new(params[:email])
```

`User.find_by_xxx` would return nil if it cannot find the corresponding object (or return the first object if there are two or more objects matched).

Comment: That won't do it, I'm actually updating a whole different model. What I'm doing it for is privilege's. If someone's not yet a member it saves their rights until they join. The privilege's are saved in the object for which they get the rights to when they join.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own before_save method equivalent and call that instead of object.save

eg.

```
def custom_save
  if email_address_exists? # this would be a method you create
    self.save
  else
    # update record in other model
  end
end
```

Then in your controller use this instead of save (ie. model.custom_save)

Comment: I don't think this solution would work if the record is being saved through a nested model. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Often I find when you are fighting against the grain of the framework so much that you are going about something the wrong way.  Is it possible your logic or model setup could be altered instead?